Inner join function, SQL, Dbeaver
I am trying to run the inner join function on Dbeaver and it is resulting in an error message

SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such
column: EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID).

I wonder if Dbeaver uses a different syntax than Microsoft SQL Server management Studio for this particular function
This is what I inputted
SELECT  * 
FROM EmployeeDemographics ed 
inner join EmployeeSalary
    on EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID 


Neither DBeaver nor SSMS have any builtin SQL syntax. They just pass the SQL code to the dbms, which will parse and execute.

What is unclear about the error message? Either you have a typo in your names or you're connecting to the wrong database.

You are aliasing your table as ed EmployeeDemographics ed but then you are calling it as EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID change your sentence to ed.EmployeeID
